# Unable to set a modern page as home page. Option missing

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have two site collections. On the first, I can make modern pages, add news articles, images etc and then set that or any page in the Site Pages folder as a home page by right clicking.

On site two, I can make the pages, but the option to set that as a home page is not there.

Both sites have the same permissions.
Both pages are checked in when trying to set it.

Whats going on here? I've spent hours on a new page for site two and now I fear I will have to modify the "default" classic home page which is not what I want to do.

Comment: Are they both modern site collections?

Comment: They are indeed. I've checked site features. Checked everything i can think of.

Comment: How do you have the "classic" home page on a modern site collection? It sounds as though one of your site collections was originally classic.

Comment: Both of the site's had classic looking pages. Don't know how. Maybe they are wiki or webpart pages?

Comment: Are you viewing the pages library using the new experience?

Comment: I am yes. On both sites.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111730/discussion-between-callum-crowley-and-darkstar-industries).

Answer (score 0):

Please go to SharePoint Designer and check if you can set the home page as shown below:

[image]

You could also try to use powershell to set home page and compare the result.

Reference:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/02/sharepoint-online-change-home-page-using-powershell.html